# How to remove white space from header elements?

Tags: html, css

I want to align the words in this div with the picture in the div next to it, but there is white space on top and bottom of my h1 and h3 elements. I am using flexbox to align them vertically and using justify content with space evenly. I have specified in CSS to remove any margin or padding on the header elements. I am stuck on this issue. I have attached a screenshot from Firefox to explain the issue I am having.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFwJw.png)

```
#card-description {
    grid-area: card-description;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    line-height: normal;
}

#card-description h1, h3 {
    line-height: normal;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: can you please share some code what you have did so far ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text is rendered in a box (content area) with a leading that causes the gap. The gap is natural and gives the text breathing room.

For alignment to the edges like your case, you can remove the gap by negative vertical margin or padding to "squeeze" the container:

```css
   padding-top: -10px;      /* adjust the value to fit your layout */
   padding-bottom: -10px;
```

And/or apply negative margin to the contained text (`margin-top` for `h1` and `margin-bottom` for `h3`).

An alternative approach you can try is decrease `line-height` of the text (effectively removing the leading)

```css
h1 {
   line-height: 1;   /* or even 0.8 for tighter distance */
}
```

But this only makes sense for one-line text only (like your `h1`) because text lines will all be squeezed together, probably not what  you want.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for you to give all the four properties 0px you can simply do.

```
margin: 0;
padding:0; <<<<< this is equivalent to what you have done.
```

As far as you question goes you can give line height to the the text element this will solve you issue.

```
line-height: normal

// You can give the value for this in many 
// forms. You can go through the 
// below given link.
```

Visit https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_line-height.asp

Comment: Thank you for your help. However, this has not worked for me. I have edited the post and provided more code.

Comment: __The line-height property defines the amount of space above and below inline elements. That is, elements that are set to display: inline or display: inline-block. This property is most often used to set the leading for lines of text.__
**The line-height property can accept the keyword values normal or none as well as a number, length, or percentage.**
**A length value can be defined using any valid CSS unit (px, em, rem, etc).**
**A percentage value is the font size of the element multiplied by the percentage**
Try something like: **1rem or 20% or 1px** just play around with the numbers.